# stackoverflow like url redirect

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to achieve what stackoverflow does with url.

domain.com/questions/1234/**properTitle** <-- fine!

domain.com/questions/1234/**wrongTitle** <-- redirect to domain.com/questions/1234/**properTitle**

But I don't want to contact the database twice.

For example, inside the question controller action, I am already querying all the info based on 1234 question Id. I do not want to redirect and lose all this information and then query again. Should I put it in TempData or something? What efficient way to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's more complicated (and maybe even less efficient) to manually cache and retrieve the data in your application. Your database server probably caches the result anyway and the second query won't take very long.

**Update:** You can redirect to an overloaded action with the model as an argument. This could look somewhat like this:

```
return RedirectToAction("Action", 
                         new { 
                               id = 1234, 
                               title = "properTitle", 
                               model = myAlreadyRetrievedModel 
                         });
```

Comment: +1. I just run it through chrome and calling the page without a title a call is made passing only the question id and a blank title. The request: `Request URL:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9274755/`. The first call has no response but seems to redirect straight to a second call. The second call is made like this: `Request URL:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9274755/stackoverflow-like-url-redirect` which then returns the page as a response. that seems to indicate that the initial action will always retrieve the model and as you said passes the title / model into a redirect.

Comment: If you pass the full title upfront though the initial request will return the response. Seem to have code in the action similar to `If title from url == title from model then return response, else return redirect using title from model` or similar.